# Meaning of these cuts on an antenna

Tags: schematics, symbol, pcb-antenna

[image]

What's the purpose of these cuts at the end of the antenna?

It is some kind of representation of an RF antenna.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iiR14r6wF-1IqbABOEFicwOYUeVuH_hd/view?usp=sharing) is the Eagle library

Edited:
[Here](https://github.com/NordicPlayground/nrf5-eagle-reference-design/tree/master/Library) Git Source Original File

Comment: Where did you get the file?  The original source may have something to say.

Comment: If it’s overlay, probably indication to cut the antenna, length matching.

Comment: In my opinion those are just indicators (wavelength?) to get the dimensions right on the first section. The designer probably copy-and-pasted this section afterwards. I wonder which layer the yellow lines correspond to - likely a comment layer.

Comment: Edited : Original Source of Library

Comment: It says 'tPlace' for the yellow color coding in Eagle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Nordic semiconductor eagle reference design](https://github.com/NordicPlayground/nrf5-eagle-reference-design)

> Antenna: In the Nordic_misc library there is supplied some suggestions for antennas, please note that antenna characteristics depends greatly on the board layout. These antennas are made according to the whitepaper on quarter wave monopole 2.45 GHz antennas. Remember to tune the antenna.

Broken link but White paper is probably: [Antenna tuning](https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/pdf/nwp_017.pdf)

> 4 Methods of tuning an antenna: There are the following two methods to tune an antenna: 1. If the physical dimensions of the antenna can be altered, for example, with a PCB antenna, adjusting the length will be one part of the tuning. Another part is to add a component, inductor, or capacitor, to pull the antenna impedance towards the 50 ohm center point. 2. If the antenna cannot be altered physically, more external components must be used to tune the antenna. These external components are called the matching network.

If the markings transfer to the PCB layout, they may be there to allow sizing the antenna for 2.4 GHz.